# Grails, Can not make spring-security event notification to work

Tags: events, grails, spring-security

I try to log logins and logouts using the event handling of spring-security but nothing happens.

I enabled event handling in Aplication.groovy:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true
```

and registered the bean in resources.groovy:

```
import grails.databinding.converters.ValueConverter
import com.torntrading.utils.DatabaseMessageSource
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver
import com.myproj.AuthenticationSuccessEventListener

beans = {
    authenticationSuccessEventListener(AuthenticationSuccessEventListener)
}
```

And the event class in folder "Utility Classes":

```
package com.myproj

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener
import org.springframework.security.authentication.event.InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent
/**
 *
 * @author Lars
 */
class AuthenticationSuccessEventListener implements    
                       ApplicationListener<InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent> {


    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
        println(springSecurityService.getPrincipal().username + "***** LOGGED IN ! ******" + new Date())    
    }
}
```

The text is never printed so I assume that the event is not fired.
What's wrong with my code?

Using version: spring-security-core:3.1.1'

Comment: What version of Grails, if it's < 3 the setting `grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true` should be in Config.groovy

Comment: | Grails Version: 3.2.4
| Groovy Version: 2.4.7
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_112

Comment: Try adding to application.yml for 3+

Comment: No idea how I should put it there. I took a chance with grails: plugin:springsecurity:useSecuritylEventListener:true but that didn't work.

Comment: Did you add it to `\init\yourApp\Application.groovy` or `\grails-app\conf\application.groovy` ?

Comment: \grails-app\conf\application.groovy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150092/discussion-between-larand-and-mike-w).